# Rails 5: Trouble downloading an HTML erb form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to send an html erb form to a user's computer as an html file. In my view, I have two buttons: "text" and "html." I have succeeded in sending a plaintext file to the user's computer when they click the "text" button, but when they click the "html" button, it just renders the erb form as if it were a view. Here is the relevant part of my controller:

```
def download
  @notecard = Notecard.find(params[:notecard_id])
  file_title = @notecard.title.downcase.tr(" ", "_")

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=#{file_title}.html"
      render :template => "notecards/download"
    end
    format.text do
      response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=#{file_title}.txt"
      render :template => "notecards/download"
    end
  end
end
```

I've  tried several other methods of handling the logic inside the "format.html do" block, including:

```
 send_data(content, filename: 'file.html', type: 'text/plain', disposition: 'attachment')
```

and:

```
render :template => "notecards/download", filename: 'file.html', type: 'text/html', disposition: 'attachment'
```

Here is the code for the button in the view:

```
= link_to "html", notecard_download_path(notecard_id: @notecard.id, format: "html")
```

I've also tried changing the content type to 'text/plain' to trick it into sending the file, based on advice I received elsewhere, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to `render_to_string` which will download the rendered file instead of the template itself.

Change this:

```
format.html do
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
  response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=#{file_title}.html"
  render :template => "notecards/download"
end
```

To this:

```
    format.html do
     # response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
     # response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=#{file_title}.html"
     # render_to_string
     send_data render_to_string, filename: 'file.html', type: 'application/html', disposition: 'attachment', layout: false}
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried the change, but it's still just displaying the template as a page.

Comment: @JGP sorry about that, you should be able to remove `:template => "notecards/download"`.  You're in your NoteCards controller and in the download action already. See revised answer.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Unfortunately, I'm still having the same issue. Any idea why it's still rendering it as a view?

Comment: made an update but havent tested.   youre somehow loading the page into the layout instead of forcing it to download.  the previous setup worked on my end oddly enough.